# Algorithmic Optimization

Tags: ruby, algorithm, performance, optimization, time

Currently I stumbled upon a question that appeared easy, so I solved it.  The problem came afterwards as the solution passed the visible tests(6856ms), but upon clicking a final submit button where my solution was further tested on hidden and quite possibly more complex tests, I get a time out error.  The catch here is my solution should satisfy all the hidden tests in under 7000ms or I will receive the time out error.  I tried vigorously to optimize the solution, but with no luck.  I am not looking for an answer, but a hint on making the algo faster would be helpful.

The object of the problem was:
Divisors of 42 are : 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42. These divisors squared are: 1, 4, 9, 36, 49, 196, 441, 1764. The sum of the squared divisors is 2500 which is 50 * 50, a square!

Given two integers m, n (1 <= m <= n) we want to find all integers between m and n whose sum of squared divisors is itself a square. 42 is such a number.

The result will be an array of arrays, each subarray having two elements, first the number whose squared divisors is a square and then the sum of the squared divisors.

My code and the time of execution of the 3 visible tests are as follows:

```
def list_squared(m, n)
p (m..n).map{|num| [num, (1..num).map{|number| number ** 2 if num % number == 0}.compact.inject(:+)]}.collect{|num, sum| [num, sum] if (1..sum).any?{|nums| nums ** 2 == sum}}.compact
end
beginning_time = Time.now
list_squared(1, 250)# [[1, 1], [42, 2500], [246, 84100]])
list_squared(42, 250)# [[42, 2500], [246, 84100]])
list_squared(250, 500)# [[287, 84100]])
end_time = Time.now
puts "Time elapsed #{(end_time - beginning_time)*1000} milliseconds" #Time elapsed 7734.796764000001 milliseconds
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The last part `if (1..sum)` is going to be excruciatingly slow. You should take the square root of `sum`, convert that to an integer `x`, and then check if `x*x == sum`.

Comment: You may get some mileage from identifying numbers that you don't need to fully calculate.  For example, no prime number can satisfy these conditions, as it will always add up to {prime number} squared plus one.  So if you can recognize that the number is prime, you can stop doing the rest of the calculation.